# VS2010,.Net 4.0 and EF 6.0.2 Errors

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I have couple of projects within a solution and few of them would have its own model and controller. For Model I can directly create them from the DB and hence I planned to use Entity Framework. But now the issue is that for one project I am able to make the EF work perfectly but in other projects I am doing the same but not able to connect the database. I am trying to connect same Oracle 11.2.0.3 database that I am using in the working project.

This is the error I am getting:

> The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

Comment: Check your reference to your db in app.config.

Comment: Did you check your web.config for the second project?

Comment: Please give your question **meaningful** question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the ODP.Net libraries. Not sure if the identified solution is correct or not. But deploying the 32 bit and 64 bit ODAC helped in resolving the issue.